# Cannot include file and got "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" warning message

Tags: php, file, include, centos

I got the following error when a file is included.

```
 Warning:  require(home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php) 
 [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
 /home2/myusername/public_html/inc/bootstrap.php on line 32

 Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 
 'home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in 
 /home2/myusername/public_html/inc/bootstrap.php on line 32
```

It is working fine in my localhost running on Windows PC. But I got that error when I uploaded the files on my shared hosting server which is CentOS.

`home2/myusername/public_html/index.php` includes `/inc/bootstrap.php` which is then trying to include `/inc/config.php`. The file `config.php` does exist on the server. `home2/myusername/public_html/` is returned by the function `getcwd()`.

The below is the first few lines of codes in bootstrap.php which issues the error.

```
define('APP_DIR', 'app');   

if( !defined('APP_ROOT') ){
    $APP_ROOT = trim(getcwd(), '/').'/';
    if(isset($_GET['bootstrap'])) $APP_ROOT .= APP_DIR . '/';
    define('APP_ROOT', $APP_ROOT);
}

if( !defined('ROOT') ){
    $ROOT = str_replace(APP_DIR, '', trim(APP_ROOT, '/'));
    if( strrpos($ROOT, '/') != strlen($ROOT)-1 ) $ROOT .= '/'; 
    define('ROOT', $ROOT);
}

# path to inc/ folder
define('INC', ROOT.'inc/');

# System configuration variables
require INC . 'config.php';
```

I have also a URL Rewrite in `/public_html/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?bootstrap [L]
```

So, when I browse `example.com/index.php`, it rewrites to `example.com/index.php?bootstrap`. It is the situation I got the error.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/public_html/
    |__ inc
    |   |__ bootstrap.php
    |   |__ config.php
    |__ .htaccess
    |__ index.php <--- I'm browsing this
```

I think the problem would be related to the absolute path file include. The relative path file include `require 'inc/bootstrap.php` in index.php is okay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 5):

If you file is located in:

`/home2/myusername/public_html/index.php`

and you bootstrap.php file to include is located in:

`/home2/myusername/public_html/inc/bootstrap.php`

your include line correctly is:

`include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/bootstrap.php";`

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is equal to /home2/myusername/public_html

Comment: `getcwd()` returns same as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: `getcwd()` gets the current working directory where the file is located, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` "always" get the root of public_html on server, not is the same.

Comment: I can't find my bootstrap.php file where can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your paths are not correctly configured. It's an easy solution most of the time. Can you please post the code of config.php and bootstrap.php where you include the files.

It's most likely that you have to change the following.

/inc/config.php to config.php.

Since it's in the same folder.

EDIT:

You are missing a '/'

```
Failed opening required 'home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php'
```

Should be this

```
'/home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php'
```

Comment: I'm browsing `/public_html/index.php`. The `config.php` is located in `/public_html/inc/'. So, I have the correct paths.

Comment: You are missing a /

`Failed opening required 
 'home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php'`
Should be this `'/home2/myusername/public_html/inc/config.php'`

Comment: Yes, it is because of missing the left `/`. I replaced `trim()` with `rtrim()`. Thanks!

Comment: Haha good thing you found it. Too bad my answer didn't really apply to your problem. But glad I could help.

Comment: You could add an **EDIT** to your answer, but do not remove the original answer. Then, I could accept your answer for the sake of further visitors.

Comment: Edited my answer with the content of the comments for future sake.